# Как сделать join двух таблиц по двум полям?

Tags: sql, join

Как сджойнить две таблицы по двум полям при условии, что иногда второе поле второй таблицы может быть `null` (в этом случае джойн нужен только по первому полю)?
1 таблица:

```
поле1 | поле2 
------------
type1 | cat1    
type1 | cat2    
type1 | cat3
```

2 таблица:

```
поле1 | поле2 
-------------
type1 | cat1    
type1 |    
type1 | cat2
```

Т.е. если поле2 не cat2 или cat1, то джоин только по поле1 (т.е. для всех категорий кроме 1 и 2 одинаковые значения)
Результат по предложению Чад

```
поле1 | поле2 
------------
type1 | cat1    
type1 | cat2    
type1 |    
type1 | cat3
```

Comment: `on (a.field1=b.field1 and (a.field2=b.field2 or b.field2 is null))` ?

Comment: А можете добавить деталей в ваш вопрос? Насколько я понял, вам в данном случае просто  подходит `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Чад, тогда выходит 2 строки по каждому джойну

Comment: Покажите результат на ЭТИХ исходных данных.

Comment: type1 | cat1    
type1 | cat2   
type1 |
type1 | cat3

Comment: А при чём тогда тут JOIN? я вижу тупой UNION [DISTINCT].

Comment: Что значит - 'две строки по каждому джойну'? Джоин один.